# Multidimensional list - Select second item if there are 2 items

Tags: r

if my question sounds confusing. Here is the example.

```
n = c('dog') 
s = c('dog', 'cat') 
b = c('dog', 'cat')
v = c('dog')
x = list(n, s, b, v)
```

The output of the above code would be

```
1.'dog'
2.'dog' 'cat'
3.'dog' 'cat'
4.'dog'
```

My goal is to get the second item when there is 2 items and get the first item when there is 1 item.

I have tried using sapply()

I can get a second element using this code.

```
sapply(x, "[", 2)
```

However, i stuck on how to write a condition above.

My desire output would be.

```
1.'dog'
2.'cat'
3.'cat'
4.'dog'
```

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: `sapply(x, tail, 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tail` to extract the last element

```
sapply(x, tail, 1)
#[1] "dog" "cat" "cat" "dog"
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_chr(x, last)
#[1] "dog" "cat" "cat" "dog"
```